# What error/exception does Paramiko throw for failed connects?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

If this fails:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect( host, username = USER , pkey = MY_KEY, timeout = 2)
```

I get a traceback like:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in bs_process
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 282, in connect
    for (family, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr) in socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I cant figure what kind/kinds of errors Paramiko throws for bad connect attempts. Which are the exception classes and how can I import them?

Comment: I catch (and re-raise) `BadHostKeyException`, `AuthenticationException`, `SSHException` and `socket.error`. There'll probably be a few more...

Comment: @Ben Obviously, `BadHostKeyException` and `AuthenticationException` are subclasses of `SSHException`. So you only need the latter...

Comment: I deal with them differently @glglgl... I probably don't need `SSHException` but it was written a while ago I wanted to be _sure_...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start by looking at the API documentation, for all classes ending in Exception:

http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect

Then, you should also catch `socket.error`. I think that will get you pretty much everything. `socket.gaierror` is a subclass of `socket.error`, for example.

Comment: Yes, `except (paramiko.SSHException, socket.error) as se:` is right

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer has a broken link.  The documentation for Paramiko now lives at:

http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect

It the "connect" method will raise the following:

```
BadHostKeyException – if the server’s host key could not be verified
AuthenticationException – if authentication failed
SSHException – if there was any other error connecting or establishing an SSH session
socket.error – if a socket error occurred while connecting
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the call to `ssh.connect()`.
In this case, is necessarily specified the connection port.
Example:

```
ssh.connect(server, port=22, username=user, pkey=key)
```

That work for me.